# Predicate in a Core Data fetch doesn't return the same results as the same predicate on a array

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

In the following example, why don't the two `properties` arrays have the same elements? The first array is empty, and the second array contains 1 element, yet they use the same predicate...

```
NSError *error;

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"publication.store.storageMode != 0 && publication.store.complete == NO && publication.download == NIL"];

NSFetchRequest *request1 = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Property"];
request1.predicate = predicate;
NSArray *properties1 = [self executeFetchRequest:request1 error:&error];

NSFetchRequest *request2 = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Property"];
NSArray *allProperties = [self executeFetchRequest:request2 error:&error];
NSArray *properties2 = [allProperties filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

- `properties1` has 0 element.
- `allProperties` has 12 elements.
- `properties2` has 1 element.

I don't understand why the first request doesn't return the one element that I get in the second method. Shouldn't they be equivalent?

Comment: Remove this line and then try  request1.predicate = predicate;

Comment: What line? I already do `request1.predicate = predicate;`. The first piece of code returns 0 result.

Comment: I mean for request2 you have not mention like this request2.predicate = predicate; Only for request1 you have set like this. So i asked to remove this line request1.predicate = predicate;

Comment: Thats's the point. Request 1 uses a predicate in the fetch request and returns no result. Request 2 uses no predicate, so it returns an array with all `Property` objects. If I use the *same* predicate on the array, I get 1 result, compared to 0 for the first case. That is what I'm trying to explain. Maybe it's because of the underlying SQLite request used by Core Data...

Comment: Does the property you get in the filtered array has nil publication or store?

Comment: I don't know what's causing the difference, but I bet that looking closely at the one element in `properties2` would provide a big clue, especially looking at what values it has for the properties mentioned in the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not to be intended as an answer, I didn't know how to write suych long text within a comment. I am not quite sure you cannot fetch with a BOOL directly in your CoreData predicate.

So I would try, for test purpose, to use two different predicates:

```
NSPredicate *predicateArray = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"publication.store.storageMode != 0 && publication.store.complete == NO && publication.download == NIL"];

NSPredicate *predicateCoreData = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"publication.store.storageMode != 0 && publication.store.complete == %@ && publication.download == NIL",[NSNumber numberWithBool:myBool]];
```

Also, I would replace NIL with nil.